# Safe usage of bitaddress.org

Tags: linux, gnupg

I want to use bitaddress.org to create a wallet. Can you please verify my approach?

1. Change the password of my router and wifi and unplug all devices from the network except my notebook.
2. Go to https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org and download the project as a .zip file.
3. Go to https://www.bitaddress.org and download the project as a .zip file.
4. Unzip both files and confirm that both resulting folders are identical with `meld`.
5. Keep one of the folders and delete the remaining files.
6. Download [pointbiz_bitaddress.org.asc](https://www.bitaddress.org/pointbiz_bitaddress.org.asc) from (at least) three trustworthy sources.
7. Disconnect my notebook from the internet.
8. Confirm that all downloaded signatures are equal with `meld`. Keep one of them.
9. `gpg --import pointbiz_bitaddress.org.asc` and confirm the ouput matches:

   gpg: key 63974F5A: public key "pointbiz pointbiz@bitaddress.org"

   imported gpg: Total number processed: 1 gpg: imported: 1 (RSA: 1)
10. `gpg --verify bitaddress.org.html.sig`. Make sure the output matches the following:

    gpg: Signature made Mon 22 Aug 2016 00:56:51 BST using RSA key ID 63974F5A

    gpg: Good signature from "pointbiz pointbiz@bitaddress.org"

    gpg: aka "ninja ninja@bitaddress.org"

    gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!

    gpg: There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.

    Primary key fingerprint: 527B 5C82 B1F6 B2DB 72A0 ECBF 8749 7B91 6397 4F5A
11. Use `bitaddress.org.html`.

I decided to not compute any hash sums as `gpg --verify` should do this already, right? Is this approach safe to be used?

Comment: If you looked at the exit scams(ftx for example) there is always a risk of using a third party for a crypto wallet, thus the safest and best way is to have a hardware wallet

Comment: Welcome to the community. Why not just use one of the secure btc wallets?.. What's wrong with that?

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with them. I am just interested in the approach mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you need to go to all the trouble of changing the password on your router, and disconnecting all the devices from your network, etc.  Also, the bitaddress web page is designed to be run offline, so all of the code needed is self contained in a single file, which you can download at https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org/raw/master/bitaddress.org.html.  Being that just this one file is needed, there is no need to download an entire project or zip file, compare sets of files with meld, etc.

So, one way to generate an offline (or 'cold') bitcoin wallet safely is to:

1. Use an online computer to download https://github.com/pointbiz/bitaddress.org/raw/master/bitaddress.org.html.
2. Copy bitaddress.org.html to a USB drive.
3. Use a Linux live boot USB to boot an offline computer into Linux.  Do not connect this computer to the network - this will be an air-gapped computer for creating the wallet.
4. Connect the USB drive containing bitaddress.org.html to the air-gapped computer.
5. Verify the authenticity of the bitaddress.org.html file, by using the command below to verify that the SHA256 checksum of the file is `dec17c07685e1870960903d8f58090475b25af946fe95a734f88408cef4aa194`:

   sha256sum bitaddress.org.html
6. If the verification is successful, open bitaddress.org.html in the browser, and proceed to create your wallet.  Copy the bitcoin private key and corresponding address to the USB drive, disconnect the USB drive, and store in a safe place.

By using this method, the bitcoin private key is generated on an air-gapped computer, and is never within the reach of a connected computer, and is never stored on any persistent storage device other than the USB drive.

*With regard to step 5 above - the SHA256 checksum above is well-known to be the authentic checksum for this file (as you'll see if you enter this checksum into Google).  You can also verify the GPG signature as well, on the air-gapped computer, with respect to the known trusted public key, to be sure.

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. So basically I could also replace the SHA256 checksum calculation with the verification I mentioned in step 10? gpg calculates a hash sum while on the fly while generating certificates, am I correct?

Comment: You're welcome, and yes that is correct, and yes what you suggested should work.  In that case, you would need both bitaddress.org.html and bitaddress.org.html.sig and the command to verify would be something like: `gpg --verify bitaddress.org.html.sig bitaddress.org.html`.

Comment: @mti2936 : Maybe somehow related. Would you mind giving my your opinion here as well?
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/275752/safe-usage-of-electrum-electrum-org-under-linux
I set up a bounty on that question.

Comment: @Ohumeronen I don't know much about Electrum, I'm more familiar with Bitcoin.  But, regardless of the type of cryptocurrency, I would suggest that you make sure your private key never touches a connected computer or computer with persitant storage - i.e. store your private key on a USB drive, and only connect that USB drive to a disconnected live-boot computer without any persistent storage.

Comment: So, to create a transaction, the general idea is: boot a disconnected computer without any storage devices using the live boot USB, install a lightweight wallet program from another USB, import the private key (from USB), create the transaction, and save the transaction to a USB.  Then, using a connected computer, upload the transaction from the USB to the blockchain.

Comment: Thank you, this goes way deeper than I thought. I think this article wraps up the idea behind it, right? https://electrum.readthedocs.io/en/latest/coldstorage.html
So I can assume that the transaction from the disconnected computer does not contain any information about my private key? Therefore I can safely copy and execute this transaction on a connected computer, right?

Comment: @Ohumeronen Yes, the steps in that article are similar to what I described.  The main difference that I see is that, in the method described in the article, the wallet persists on the offline computer.  Correct that the signed transaction created on the offline computer should not contain the private key (or any information that can be used to derive the private key).

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot. I intend to only create transactions on an offline live boot USB which I will flush after the signed transaction is broadcast.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151740/discussion-between-mti2935-and-ohumeronen).